# Scrollbar thumb is reaching scrollbar track too early

Tags: android, scrollbar, horizontalscrollview

Please have a look at the [video](https://streamable.com/87dds).

As you can see, I have `HorizontalScrollView` and inside I have inserted many dummy circles. The problem I am facing is that `scrollbar thumb` width is quite large and **`thumb` reaches the end of track even though there are more circles to scroll.**

The same thing happened when i scolled back again. `thumb` stays at the end of the `track` for little while and then starts moving towards the start of `track`. I have read the documentation and searched the net for little while. No success  :(. What am I missing here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of that make a custom view and manage scroll through touch events?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO i have never tried anything like this. Could you provide any links on how it is done?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect-all-supported-gestures

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll#term